# Даны 2 матрицы. Нужно с некоторым шагом двигать одну поверх другой и перемножать соответствующие элементы

Tags: python, массивы, алгоритм, numpy, матрицы

Задача такая։

> Даны 2-мерные numpy массивы 'a' и 'b' с размерами mxn и kxk
> соответственно, целые числа 'padding' и 'stride' и функция f, нужно։
>
> 1. Добавить 'padding' столбцов/строк нулей со всех сторон матрицы а,
> 2. Двигать 'b' с шагом 'stride' по матрице 'a' перемножая соответствующие элементы,
> 3. Сложить все элементы получившегося kxk массива,
> 4. Применить функцию f на эту сумму,
> 5. Результат положить в итоговую матрицу.

С первым пунктом я уже разобрался, нужно применить функцию `np.pad()`, поэлементное перемножение матриц тоже не трудно реализовать, как и сложение и применение функции, но я не могу разобраться, как реализовать шаги, кроме того, что делать, если шаг слишком большой, например в матрице

```
a = np.array([[1, 1, 2],
              [0, 1, 3],
              [1, 3, 0],
              [4, 5, 2]])
b = np.array([[1, 0],
              [0, 1]])
```

с шагом 2. В первой итерации будет

```
[1, 1]
[0, 1]
```

но какую матрицу мы должны взять во второй?

Answer (score 0):

Если добавить `padding = 1`, то на втором шаге будет

```
[2, 0]
[3, 0]
```

и на следующих

```
[1, 3]
[4, 5]

[0, 0]
[2, 0]
```

Для шага 1 это похоже на реализация свёртки в лоб.

Возможно, авторы что-то другое имели в виду, но для этого недостаточно информации.